# Spam/Offensive flags should have a description in moderator tools

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

Today I have a flag in the moderator tools which has no description where normally it will say "Not an answer", etc. In the right hand column, there is a summary stating "1 Spam/Offensive Flags," so clearly that refers to this one flag on the site.

My request is that the flag itself should say "Spam/Offensive" in it, same as it does for other flag types, and for offensive comment flags.

[image]

Comment: Spam/offensive flags have never had descriptions there, as far as I know.

Comment: @mmyers: Interesting. I could have sworn I'd seen descriptions on those before...

Comment: I swear I've seen spam/offensive show up before too, maybe just for comments though

Comment: @BenBrocka: Ah yes... come to think of it, it was probably comments where I had seen it, too.

Comment: @Flimzy I _think_ for spam/offensive flags there's a tooltip saying so, but no description. Hover over the red 1 to check it out.

Comment: +1, it needs to be made much more obvious what these flags are and what's being flagged.  I always miss the sidebar, the info should be front and center like with other flag types.

Comment: @MatthewRead Well, the flag indicator is a different color; I think that's how you're supposed to know

Comment: Still, it doesn't even differentiate between spam or offensive

Comment: Oh, I think remember something that was confusing me -- comments flagged as offensive look like they're a flag on the original question/answer, with the comment being the content of a "for moderator attention" flag.  Before I knew that red represented special flags that was seriously confusing.  Having all flags with a text blurb, rather than having a special case to *remove* information, is definitely what I would prefer.

Answer (score 2):

This might or might not have been introduced with the [new flag dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328838/295232), but it clearly says 'spam' now, not just a red indicator:

[image]